# Make webpage font auto-resizable based on dynamic type in iOS

Tags: html, css, fonts, webkit, accessibility

I want my website to adapt dynamic font-size for iOS. So If you change font-size in settings (Settings > General > Accessibility > Larger Text on your iPhone), your webpage font-size should adjust based on that.

I have `font: -apple-system-body` added in html root. And throughout the website I am using `rem` to adjust font-size relative to html root.
So it's working but the problem is `-apple-system-body` gives `font-size: 16px` by default which is too high for my page. I want to convert that to `10px;` So my html root font-size should be 62.5% of what the system gives always.

Currently I am achieving that using javascript with something like this :

```
document.documentElement.style.fontSize = document.documentElement.style.fontSize * 0.625;
```

Was wondering if there's css only way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css `calc()` function. Inside this function, you can perform operations. For example:

```
font-size: calc(1rem * 0.625);
```

For more info: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this and it always returns `10px`. I think in this case it takes `1rem` as `16px` always irrespective of system font size.

Comment: I put “1rem” as an example. You can put any font size you want instead of 1rem

Comment: It's not fixed. I would want to have system given font-size instead of `1rem`. But I don't know how I can get that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set the HTML size to 62.5%. This will honour system settings (the 10px is a fallback for ancient browsers, not really needed)

```
html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Ensure you definitely have `rem` or `em` units everywhere if you do this though.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. I always get `10px` at the html root. my html css is 
```font: -apple-system-body;
font-size: 62.5%;```

Comment: you may need to force close safari and then restart for this to take effect. If that doesn't work then there is something else going on as the above is the way to do it. Do you want to share a fiddle that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Here's a basic one. https://jsfiddle.net/nnIIInnjA/j8uwn6ms/7/
I have create this in my system and checking it on ios Simulator. I am getting 10px always though I am changing font-size in accessibility.

Comment: Hey Graham, I would really appreciate your help. Please let me know if i am making a mistake somewhere. Thank you :)